# Fusion of odometry from different sourses

Tags: navigation, ekf, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have three different sensor generating odometry . The three sources are

1. laser
2. Wheel
3. camera
   i want to fuse these odometry using robot localization package .

Do the fame_id of the all the sources generating odometry be parent odom child base_link or it should be different for different  source ( odom_laser-->base_link) ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249447/fusion-of-odometry-from-different-sourses/) by [shashank](https://answers.ros.org/users/25836/shashank/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2016-12-05

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2016-12-06**:
Missing details to answer: The point of the whole tf tree is to link the different objects (e.g. sensors) together. One sensor could be e.g. rotated by 90° or placed 1m away. The tf then needs to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is tricky because if you're fusing N>1 Odometry messages, each Odometry needs a unique frame for header.frame_id.

Since frames can only have one parent, these frames (such as the proposed odom_laser) typically end up *children* of base_link, and **must** be broadcast by your components, while the fused odom frame broadcast by robot_localization ends up the *parent* of base_link.

Another approach may be to have your sensors publish TwistWithCovarianceStamped, which will be transformed to the local frame of the vehicle and does not require a distinct coordinate frame.

See http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/robot_localization/html/preparing_sensor_data.html

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2016-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shashank](https://answers.ros.org/users/25836/shashank/) on 2016-12-07**:
according to my understanding your are saying that my frame ids should be ( base_link-->laser_odom , base_link--> camera_odom, base_link-->wheel_odom) . The ekf_localization should publish me odom-->base_link. Am i correct ???

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2016-12-07**:
that's correct

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2016-12-19**:
Note that the odometry messages/inputs can have the same `frame_id`, but unless the measurements are in agreement with each other (e.g., `odom0` and `odom1` both provide measurements that don't diverge), it's going to produce ugly results. I try to stick to one pose and N velocity inputs.

**Comment by [shashank](https://answers.ros.org/users/25836/shashank/) on 2016-12-20**:
So u are saying i should choose the pose input from the most reliable source of odometry(say laser odometry) and for rest odometry (camera,wheel)  source i should only choose twist(velocity) messages and omit out pose. Am i correct??

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2017-01-04**:
Yes, correct.

**Comment by [Abdur](https://answers.ros.org/users/83117/abdur/) on 2022-03-31**:
I have the same confusion. As per the comments, did you set the frames `laser_odom` , `camera_odom` and `wheel_odom` as the children of base_link ? That cant work for me because these are the fixed frames..

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2022-04-14**:
If those frames are from sensors that are onboard the robot, then yes, they should be children of `base_link`. If they come from an external reference like a motion capture system, they would not be. You'd want a transform from your EKF world frame directly to that frame.

Note that the case of pose data that is being generated from a sensor onboard the robot where the sensor is not aligned with the vehicle origin is not well supported, but will be once [this](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/pull/728) PR is merged. Then you can do something different: make the `child_frame_id` in the odom message your sensor frame (e.g., `camera_odom`) and set `odomN_pose_use_child_frame` to true, and then also set `odomN_differential` to true.